# How to read from text file, split strings from integers and then pass integers into an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

so I am very new to programming and have been trying out some exercises to better learn java.

Right now, I have a program that reads exam marks from a text file(contains only integers exclusively) and then passes that onto the arraylist.

Something like:

```
exammarks.txt file contains:
23 45 67 76 12


Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("exammarks.txt");
ArrayList<Integer> marksArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (fileScan.hasNextInt())
{
    marksArray.add(fileScan.nextInt());
}

Print out: [23, 45, 67, 76, 12]
```

However I would like to modify this so that the exammarks.txt file contains:

```
name grade
NAME 56
NAME2 67
NAME3 43
```

and that the program reads this text file, ignores the first line, then splits the strings from the integers and then adds the integers onto the ArrayList.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: so your second code block is what you want to work with?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your prefered input and prefered output?

Comment: You can use `regexp` to analyse your strings on each line and extract only the numbers. Checkout the [regexp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation.

Comment: If you use [`String#split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) with a single whitespace as the argument, the last element of the resulting array should be a String containing your number, which you can then parse to an Integer object. May be worth trimming any excess whitespace off each line to be on the safe side before you do the split.

Comment: Beside `nextInt` Scanner has also other methods like `nextLine` `next` or `hasNext*TypeName*`. Try to use them and come back if you will have any *specific* problems.

Comment: @Aelop yes that is correct, that is how the text file will be written out

Comment: so it is not how the textfile you read looks like?

Comment: @Aelop Yes, each line has a student name and then their exam mark next to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your snippet and extend it to read the second .txt file aswell.

Your while loop now has to loop over `lines`.

```
fileScan.nextLine(); // skip first line
    while (fileScan.hasNextLine())
    {
        marksArray.add(Integer.valueOf(fileScan.nextLine().split(" ")[1]));
    }
```

So what happens here is that first you get the `nextLine`, split it by `" "` and get the second part where the `Integer` sits. But since `nextLine` returns a String which is split in two Strings you have to cast it to `Integer` or use the static method `Integer.valueOf`.

Comment: does this also skip the first line?

Comment: @Aelop Now it does.

Comment: @MuratK. Are the names in your input file 100% guaranteed to never contain a whitespace? If they might, the hardcoded `[1]` will cause you problems.

Comment: @JonK I don't know if it does or not. I worked with the given example.

Comment: Yeah, I @ pinged the wrong person with my comment - sorry about that, was actually intended for @FuadAliKalanya